# GIT con Django - Failed to push son refs

Tags: git, github, git-push

Al intentar hacer push para volcar de local a github, me devuelve el siguiente error:

¿Qué sucede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer commit se me abre el editor automaticamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto, debes actualizar primero tu local para que refleje algunos cambios que hay en el repositorio remoto (GitHub), tal vez algún commit o un rebase.

Debería solucionarse con un git pull, tal y como lo indica el mensaje:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Y posteriormente puedes hacer el `git push origin`

Comment: me devuelve fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories. ¿Qué puede suceder?

Comment: ¿con cuál comando aparece dicho mensaje?

Comment: He añadido la captura de imagen del comando que has comentado con su respuesta. Me refiero con el comando: git pull origin master Gracias.

Comment: Revisa la edición de la respuesta.

Comment: funciona bien con git pull origin master --allow-unrealated-histories Gracias.